# If $f^3,~\bar{f}^2$ are holomorphic on a domain $D$, then $f$ is constant on $D$.

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $D$ be an open and connected region on the complex plane and $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function such that 
>   $f^3,~\bar{f}^2$ are holomorphic. Prove that $f$ is constant on $D$.

*Attempt*. A classic technique is such cases is to show that 
$f'(z)=0$ on $D$. I have thought of $Ref$ or $Im f$, in case they are constant, but I don't seem to get the desired result that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $f^3$ and $\overline{f}^2$ are holomorphic, so is $|f|^{12}$.

Comment: Maybe something like this: $(f^3)^2=f^6,~(\bar{f}^2)^3=\bar{f}^6$ are holomorphic, so $f^6\bar{f}^6=|f|^{12}$ is holomorphic and therefore $|f|$ is constant. But how does it follow that $f$ is constant?

Comment: then we get $|f^3|$ constant, which implies $f^3$ is constant by maximimum modulus or open mapping theorem